# Can I use _lodash to update an array with data from another?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array called grid.data that has an assignedTo field which is a Id value (25 and 26) in this example. I also have another array called userProfiles that has an id and a name field.

```
var grid.data = [
   {"cityId":9,"assignedTo":"25"},
   {"cityId":63,"assignedTo":"26"}];

var userProfiles = [
   {"id":"25","name":"john"},
   {"id":"26","name":"jacky"}];
```

I have the following function:

```
var getUser = function (userId) {
    if (userId && userProfiles)
        for (var i = 0; i < userProfiles.length; i++)
            if (userProfiles[i].id === userId)
                return userProfiles[i].name;
    return '';
}
```

Is it possible for me to use _lodash to call the getUser function with 
the assignedTo values and replace the assignedTo with the user name 
that's returned? Alternatively (if it's a better way), could I combine the grid.data and the $scope.option.userProfiles with _lodash and avoid having to call getUser?

This is the output I need:

```
var grid.newData = [
   {"cityId":9,"assignedTo":"john"},
   {"cityId":63,"assignedTo":"jacky"}];
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post both arrays, and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could combine an `_.map` and a `_.where`....

```
grid.newData = _.map(grid.data, function(item) {
    var profile = _.where(userProfiles, {id : item.assignedTo})[0];
    return {
        cityId : item.cityId,
        assignedTo : profile.name
    }
});
```

Comment: what happens if `_.where(userProfiles, {id : item.assignedTo}).length` is greater than 1?

Comment: OP asked for a lodash mapping function and gave a one-to-one example. Unless s/he speaks of a need to move `assignedTo` into an array in the `> 1` case, there's no need to offer up that solution.

Answer (score -2):

You could just do it with vanilla.js:

```
var grid_data = [
   {"cityId":9,"assignedTo":"25"},
   {"cityId":63,"assignedTo":"26"}];

var userProfiles = [
   {"id":"25","name":"john"},
   {"id":"26","name":"jacky"}];

var output = []

// loop over the grid data and the user profiles.
for(var o = 0, olen = grid_data.length; o < olen; ++o) {
  for(var i = 0, ilen = userProfiles.length; i < ilen; ++i) {

    // skip pairs that don't match.
    if(grid_data[o].assignedTo !== userProfiles[i].id) {
      continue
    }

    output.push({
      cityId: grid_data[o].cityId,
      assignedTo: userProfiles[i].name
    })
  }
}

console.log(output)
//  [ { cityId: 9, assignedTo: 'john' },
//    { cityId: 63, assignedTo: 'jacky' } ]
```

Or, if you prefer a more functional approach:

```
console.log(grid_data.map(join).reduce(flatten, []))

function join(city) {
  return userProfiles.filter(matches).map(merge)

  function merge(profile) {
    return {
      cityId: city.cityId,
      assignedTo: profile.name
    }
  }

  function matches(profile) {
      return profile.id === city.assignedTo
  }

}

function flatten(lhs, rhs) {
  return lhs.concat(rhs)
}
```

Finally lodash (expands @el_bob's answer)

```
var _ = require('lodash')

console.log( _.flatten(_.map(grid_data, function(city) {
  return _.map(_.where(userProfiles, {id : city.assignedTo}), merge)

  function merge(profile) {
    return {
      cityId: city.cityId,
      assignedTo: profile.name
    }
  }
})))
```

Comment: -1...  if user is asking how to do it in lodash i.e. functionally, for loops are out of scope.

Comment: lodash supports for loops.

Comment: but I will provide a lodash example as well.